# What is the difference between clicking on input with a mouse and selecting it with tab?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this input field:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-xs" dropdown>
  <input id="simple-btn-keyboard-nav" ng-model="available_fields_query" id="single-button" dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled" placeholder="Add New Field" focus-me="true">
  </input>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="btn-append-to-body">
    <li role="menuitem" ng-repeat="item in availableFields | iwSearch: available_fields_query">
      <a href="#" ng-click="addField(item)">{{item | toUserListHeader}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And if I click it(click on input) everything is working, dropdown/search/model/filter works, but if I focus it with Tab it does nothing, so I guess there is a difference between clicking on an element and focusing it with a tab.

How can I trigger all the same functions with a tab select, like if I was clicking on an element?

Comment: Your getting it wrong, Tab is used to get the focus, in order to click on an element with the keyboard, use Tab to get the focus, then press Enter to "click" it.

Comment: @ThibaudL it still doesn't trigger the function from angular-ui that creates dropdown menu. Even if i press Enter after I "click" on it. To trigger the dropdown I still have to actually "click" on it to trigger everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @ThibaudL pointed out, the `click` event differs from the `focus` event since it triggers the `focus` event as well whereas the `focus` does not trigger the `click`.

If you want to call `addField(item)` on both events, I suggest using [`ng-focus`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus) instead of `ng-click`.

Comment: Well it's not only about ```addFiled(item)```, when I click on the input field I trigger something in angular-ui that creates a dropdown list, then I can use my kb or mouse to select specific field(each filed is a link). Also when I select the field with TAB and then press enter it still does nothing.

Comment: So, what about a neat little workaround where you trigger the click event on `ng-focus` or a custom *directive*?

Comment: I'm thinking about triggering click event on ng-focus, not sure how and where to do it.

Comment: The same way you were using `addField(item)` but now just trigger it by jQuery: `element.trigger('click');`